# Degree of field extension $k(t_1^{\frac{1}{p}}, \dots, t_n^{\frac{1}{p}})/k(t_1, \dots, t_n)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $p>0$ and consider $L:=k(t_1, \dots, t_n)$ to be the fraction field of the ring of polynomials over $k$ in n variables. Say $M:=k(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ is another copy of $L$. Then we can map $L$ into $M$ via mapping $k$ to itself and $t_i \mapsto x_i^p$ for all $i =1, \dots, n$. I am trying to find the degree of the field extension $M/L$ or in other words $k(t_1^{1/p}, \dots, t_n^{1/p})/k(t_1, \dots, t_n)$. In the case that $n=1$ we get that $M=k(t_1)[x]/(x^p-t)$ and since this polynomial is irreducible in characteristic $p$, we get that $[M:L]=p$. Is it true, that in general $[M:L]=p^n$?

Comment: I think the solution could look be using the tower of field extensions where each intermediate step is $k(t_1^{1/p}, \dots, t_m^{1/p}, t_{m+1}, \dots, t_n)$ as field extension of $k(t_1^{1/p }, \dots, t_{m-1}^{1/p}, t_m, \dots, t_n)$ and all of those have degree $p$ by the above.

Comment: Correct. If the $t_i$s are algebraically independent transcendentals over $k$, that's all there is to it.